# Write complex query in Couchbase with date field?

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I am not much in db thing and the challenge here for me is with N1QL query. My document looks something like this below

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-06-30 18:40:12",
  "title": "http://www.sample.com",
  "clicks": 0,
  "keyword": "7s9HHp",
  "expiryDays": 90,
  "user": "admin",
  "url": "http://www.sample.com",
  "ip": "192.12.35.40"
}
```

Now I want select all the documents whose `timestamp` and current timestamp difference is either greater or same as `expiryDays`. In short select all whose (Current Timestamp - 2017-06-30 18:40:12)>=90 days.

I checked in [Couchbase portal](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html) they support date difference like below

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF_STR('2016-05-18T03:59:00Z', '2016-05-15 03:59:00Z', 'day') as add_3_days;
```

But don't know how to do in java. My query possibly look something like below

```
Statement statement = Select.select("*").from("My_Bucket").where("Don't know what to supply here");
```

Comment: I post this question in Couchbase forum and got the answer. Please refer this [link](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/select-all-document-id-from-exactly-x-days-ago/13313).

Answer (score 0):

refer to https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/sdk/java/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html to use DSL with N1QL. In summary, you have two ways:

1. pass the SELECT query string to query() method.
2. or, use date functions (see API [reference](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.4.6/)  com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.functions) after the DSL query as you mentioned. Infact, you can specify projecting fields to select() method instead of *

Comment: Yes, I got the ans. Thanks